# How to repair my Python installation on CentOS 6.5

Tags: python, linux, centos

I have installed python 2.7 some time ago don't know what was happend but now is not working correctly. Is hard to me to describe my problem, but:
- when I login as root I install python2.7 using `yum install python27` (I also install pip2.7) and using pip2.7 install `pushbullety.py` and it's works then I logout and login as normal user I create .py script with pushbullet import and when I run it using `python2.7 myscrip.py` then got message that there no module pushbullet then I relog to root user and try check it as root when I type `python2.7 myscript.py` then got message `bash: python2.7: command not found`.
I think that I have two version python2.7 installed but dunno how to check it, can anyone help me how to remove all previous installed python version (only left oryginal 2.6 version) and proper install python2.7 again for all users use?
Maybe it help a little, I try to find all python* files on my centos I type `find / -name python*` and result is [here](http://pastebin.com/QF4NLKKJ)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

first, centos depend on python for **a lot** of components.

can you please share the output of `rpm -qa |grep python` and the output of `which python` and `which python2.7` here?

in any case - when you `yum install python` and when you `yum install python2.7` you get two different versions of python but both 2.7.

btw, are you trying to work inside virtual environment (VENV) ?